# Two 'Sheet' Classes inside Apache POI jar

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Inside the Apache POI jar I see there are two Sheet kind of classes, org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet and org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet. What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`High level representation of a SpreadsheetML worksheet. - XSSFSheet` . This is to be used when you are  dealing with `Excel data saved in XML format`.  Docs are [here](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFSheet.html)

`High level representation of a Excel worksheet.- Sheet` . This is the normal excel spreadsheet.

Comment: High level representation of a Excel worksheet.- Sheet -> Does it vary based on office version?

Comment: if i wanted to handled multiple version of Excel version file which one do i need to use it?

Comment: can you please clarify multiple versions of excel version file

Answer (score 4):

Actually there are more than two: `Sheet` is the general interface, and it has several implementations: `HSSFSheet` (for xls), `XSSFSheet` (for xlsx), `SXSSFSheet` (some streaming stuff), etc.

You should generally use `Sheet`, which works with any kind of Excel document. Only when you need some special features you should probably look into the implementation classes.